# yawsso can't find the right awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, aws-cli

I am trying to use `yawsso` to login to aws. I have `awscliv2` installed by following the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).

Unfortunately I also seem to have aws version 1 on my computer as well.

So when I try

`yawsso login --profile my-profile --this -e`

I get the response:

`Required AWS CLI v2. Found aws-cli/1.27.62 Python/3.9.13 Darwin/21.6.0 botocore/1.29.62`

But `awscli2 --version` returns:

```
2.2.0
AWS CLI v2 command: docker run -i --rm -v /Users/tomkealy/.aws:/root/.aws -v /Users/tomkealy/my-folder:/aws amazon/aws-cli
aws-cli/2.9.20 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.10.47-linuxkit docker/x86_64.amzn.2 prompt/off
```

`which aws` returns `/Users/tomkealy/opt/anaconda3/bin/aws`

and `aws --version` returns

```
aws-cli/1.27.62 Python/3.9.13 Darwin/21.6.0 botocore/1.29.62
```

How do I fix this so that `yawsso` finds the version 2 of the aws-cli?

I have tried to uninstall `aws` via conda and brew. To no success.

Comment: Interesting, what is `awscli2` ?  I'm not aware of any version of the AWS tools that install that, or that use Docker.

Comment: It's version 2 of the aws-cli.

Comment: From where?  The [installation guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) doesn't mention it, and it's not on a Windows, Mac or Linux machine with AWS CLI v2 installed.

Comment: I honestly don't know from where!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by uninstalling awscli

```
pip uninstall awscli -y
```

which meant that `which aws` now pointed to

```
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

but `aws --version` now errored:

```
-bash: /Users/tomkealy/opt/anaconda3/bin/aws: No such file or directory
```

and I fixed THAT with

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/aws-cli`

now `which aws` gives
`/usr/local/bin/aws`

and `aws --version` prints

`aws-cli/2.9.20 Python/3.11.1 Darwin/21.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off`